# GNU make issue: "No rule to make target `pjsip.h', needed by `main.o'"

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have been working to write my first makefile and after following some tutorials and reading some links on stackoverflow I managed to write the file, what I am doing is

- using .a files from the pjsip api, notice the variables **PJSIP, PJLIB_UTIL** and **PJLIB**
- define the path to the .h file using the -I option, see the variables **PJSIP_HDR, PJLIB_HDR** and **PJLIB_U_HDR**

I get the following error:

```
 make: ***No rule to make target `pjsip.h', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.
```

It believe that it is usefull to mention that I have only 4 **#includes** in my **.cpp** file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pjsip.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
```

The goal is to have a file called **main** which I can excute, I am using **Ubuntu 14.04** . Here is my makefile

```
CC = g++
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -Wall -c $(DEBUG)
LFLAGS = -Wall $(DEBUG)
PJSIP = -L/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/lib -llibpjsip-simple-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a -llibpjsip-ua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a -llibpjsip-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a -llibpjsua2-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a -llibpjsua-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
PJLIB = -L/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib/lib -llibpj-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
PJLIB_UTIL = -L/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib-utils/lib -llibpjlib-util-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a
PJSIP_HDR = -I/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/include/
PJLIB_HDR = -I/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib/include/
PJLIB_U_HDR = -I/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib-utils/include

main: main.o
        $(CC) $(LFLAGS) main.o -o main

main.o: main.cpp pjsip.h pjlib.h pjlib-utils.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(PJSIP_HDR) $(PJLIB_HDR) $(PJLIB_U_HDR) main.cpp $(PJSIP) $(PJLIB) $(PJLIB_UTIL)

clean:
         \rm -f *.o
```

Any extra comments that might help me improve my makefile are welcomed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try writing the command line yourself first before you start making Makefiles.

Comment: I jusd did as you recomended, when I do so I get an output which makes me believe that I have a mistake in linking the .a and including the .h files. is some of the output: main.cpp:(.text+0x1da): undefined reference to `pj_init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `pjlib_util_init'
main.cpp:(.text+0x27f): undefined reference to `pj_pool_factory_default_policy'

Comment: In this case, the cpp file is not the problem: make is telling you it can't find a neccesary file for the recipe. I find odd that you do "PJSIP_HDR = -I/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/include/pjsip.h" and then use it with the -I directive... Have you tried removing the filename from the definition?. When you use -I you should be using include paths, right?.

Comment: yes I did tried to do so, my original line was                                 "PJSIP_HDR = -I/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/include/"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you specify the pjsjp.h as dependency (i.e., after the ":" in the line for `main.o` target); but `make` doesn't know how to find the include file `pjsip.h` - it doesn't interpret the `-I ...` options, these are only for the g++ command.

You could try to specify an absolute path, something like this:

```
PJLIB_HEADER_DIR=/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib/include
main.o: main.cpp $(HEADER_DIR)/pjlib.h ...
```

(...and similar for other headers)
By the way, the "-I" option only accepts directories (see the g++ [documentation on directory search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0/gcc_3.html#SEC17)), thus the definition of `PJSIP_HDR` with the header file name in it makes no sense, it should just be:

```
PJSIP_HDR = -I/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/include/
```

You probably added the header name because of the error?

The second, easier option is to simply remove those external dependencies. Just write

```
main.o: main.cpp
```

that is, leave out all the library header files. Dependecies are there to tell make to rebuild stuff if a dependency has changed. I assume those pjsip.h, pjlib.h, ... come from an external library which you are not changing often? Then making it a dependency in make isn't really necessary.

By the way, these days make files are hardly written by hand; they are typically generated by tools such as [cmake](http://cmake.org/).

Comment: I get the following error after I edit it according to your recomendations make: *** No rule to make target `/home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/include//pjsip.h', needed by `main.o'.  Stop.

Comment: I probably had the wrong path in there. Check under which path the pjsip.h file actually exists. But also check the second, simpler option you have, which I now added to the answer: just leaving out the external header dependencies.

Comment: Removing the dependencies has solved the problem and thanks for recommending cmake as well. I will mark this answer as correct.

Comment: "PJSIP" indeed is a third-party library, and `pjsip.h` is a header from PJSIP. The second suggestion is correct; this does not need to be a dependency, just as `<iostream>` isn't.

Answer (score 3):

The following rule:

```
main.o: main.cpp pjsip.h pjlib.h pjlib-utils.h
```

specifies that `main.o` requires all the listed files in order to be built.

You do not have any file named `pjsip.h` in the current directory. This is what `make` is telling you: this file does not exist, and there is no explicit rule to create this file.

The error message you showed is from `make`. `make` doesn't look at, and doesn't care that you pass some `-I` flag to some strangely-named command called `g++` that gets executed to build `main.o`. `make` knows nothing about `g++`, nor about any flags passed to it. All that makes knows, or cares about, are the explicitly listed targets and rules.

Comment: Sam is right here. When you specify all those file paths, these are not for "make" but for your compile chain. Where are these header files located?.

Comment: Even if I write the whole path to the files, it does not solve the problem. Here is the locations of the files, but as I mentioned wrtitting a full path does not help                                                                           /home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjsip/include/                                               /home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib/include/                                              /home/ubuntu/pjsip/trunk/pjlib-utils/include

Comment: "It still doesn't work" is not a useful problem description.